# Make fetched messages case insensitive Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

As some of you maybe remember I tried to write a command which checks a channel if a specific key word exists in its messages. The most crucial part of this code is here:

```js
banlist.messages.fetch({limit : 30}).then(messages => {
            let positive = messages.some(msgs => msgs.content.includes(check))
            if(positive === false) {
               ...
            }
            else{
               ...
            }
```

Unfortunately the problem arose really quick that this check for the key word is case sensitive. Is there any way to make it case insensitive?
I know of the `.toLowerCase()` but that only works for commands and I dont recall it working for fetched messages. Looking forward to your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.toLowerCase()` is a string method, it will work for any string.

Lowercase both strings being compared to level them.

```js
let positive = messages
   .some(msgs => msgs.content.toLowerCase().includes(check.toLowerCase()))
```